# Limit of a function in R^2 at a point.

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $S$ be the set of $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \to 0$ as $(x, y) \to 0$. Then $S$ is contained in

1. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha , \beta > 0\}$.
2. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha , \beta > 2\}$
3. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha + \beta > 1\}$.
4. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha + 4\beta > 1\}$

As- 3

Put $y = mx$, we get $$\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{x^{\alpha + \beta -1}m^{\beta}}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} \to 0 $$ provided $\alpha + \beta  > 1$ whenever  $(x, y) \to 0$. Thus, $$S=\{(\alpha, \beta)\in \mathbb{R}^2, \ \alpha + \beta  > 1\}$$

1. Incorrect as $S$ contains negative $\alpha$ and $\beta$'s.
2. Incorrect by $(1)$.
3. Correct as for any $\alpha, \beta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\alpha + \beta  > 2$  implies $\alpha + \beta  > 1$.
4. Incorrect as $(3, -1)$ is in the set $S$ but not in the set  $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha + 4\beta > 1\}$.

Is my solution correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq \sqrt{2}|x|^{1/2}|y|^{1/2}$$ we get
$$\frac{|x|^{\alpha}|y|^{\beta}}{\sqrt{2}|x|^{1/2}|y|^{1/2}}$$ we get

$$\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|x|^{\alpha-1/2}|y|^{\beta-1/2}$$ so we obtain $$\alpha+\beta>1$$